# Whats the reason for my app is getting force closed every single time?

Tags: android, xml

im trying to make a music application and just made my listview of songs list and its getting force closed. i have mentioned the user permissions for reading the external storage then also... here's the code

```
package com.smp.ravirathore.music;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class FileList extends AppCompatActivity {



TextView text_list;
ImageView backimg;
ListView listsongs;
String[] genuinesongs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_list);
    backimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    text_list = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_list);
    listsongs = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_songs);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "journal.ttf");
    text_list.setTypeface(font);
    ArrayList<File> songs = find(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    genuinesongs = new String[songs.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i <= songs.size(); i++) {

        genuinesongs[i] = songs.get(i).getName().toString().replace("mp3","");
    }
   ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.activity_file_list,
   R.id.text_list, genuinesongs);
   listsongs.setAdapter(adp);
}

public ArrayList<File> find(File root){
    ArrayList<File> arrayList = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] files = root.listFiles();
    for(File single : files){
        if(single.isDirectory() && !single.isHidden()){
            arrayList.addAll(find(single));
        }
        else{
            if(single.getName().endsWith(".mp3") || single.getName().endsWith(".wav")){
            arrayList.add(single);
        }
    }


}
    return arrayList;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_file_list, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

Also the xml files which i have used are given below

activity_file_list.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FileList">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list_songs"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

word_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#bdbdbd"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:id="@+id/text_list"
        android:padding="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And lastly my AndroidMenifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.smp.ravirathore.music" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".FileList">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the logcat :

```
 09-24 16:08:43.105    7201-7201/com.smp.ravirathore.music D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
09-24 16:08:43.365    7201-7201/com.smp.ravirathore.music D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-24 16:08:43.365    7201-7201/com.smp.ravirathore.music W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x64d62b20)
09-24 16:08:43.365    7201-7201/com.smp.ravirathore.music W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/.tmp/.crashed_app: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-24 16:08:43.365    7201-7201/com.smp.ravirathore.music W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
09-24 16:08:43.365    7201-7201/com.smp.ravirathore.music D/AndroidRuntime﹕ procName from cmdline: com.smp.ravirathore.music
09-24 16:08:43.365    7201-7201/com.smp.ravirathore.music E/AndroidRuntime﹕ in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.smp.ravirathore.music
09-24 16:08:43.365    7201-7201/com.smp.ravirathore.music E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FileNotFoundException while trying to write in crash app file
09-24 16:08:43.375    7201-7201/com.smp.ravirathore.music W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
09-24 16:08:43.455    7216-7216/com.smp.ravirathore.music D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
09-24 16:08:43.535    7216-7216/com.smp.ravirathore.music D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-24 16:08:43.535    7216-7216/com.smp.ravirathore.music W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x64d62b20)
09-24 16:08:43.545    7216-7216/com.smp.ravirathore.music D/AndroidRuntime﹕ procName from cmdline: com.smp.ravirathore.music
09-24 16:08:43.545    7216-7216/com.smp.ravirathore.music E/AndroidRuntime﹕ in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.smp.ravirathore.music
09-24 16:08:43.545    7216-7216/com.smp.ravirathore.music W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/.tmp/.crashed_app: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-24 16:08:43.545    7216-7216/com.smp.ravirathore.music W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
09-24 16:08:43.545    7216-7216/com.smp.ravirathore.music W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
09-24 16:08:43.545    7216-7216/com.smp.ravirathore.music W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
09-24 16:08:43.545    7216-7216/com.smp.ravirathore.music W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:42)
09-24 16:08:43.545    7216-7216/com.smp.ravirathore.music W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.writeCrashedAppName(RuntimeInit.java:145)
09-24 16:08:43.545    7216-7216/com.smp.ravirathore.music W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.sendCrashReport(RuntimeInit.java:134)
09-24 16:08:43.545    7216-7216/com.smp.ravirathore.music W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.access$100(RuntimeInit.java:53)
09-24 16:08:43.545    7216-7216/com.smp.ravirathore.music W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:80)
09-24 16:08:43.545    7216-7216/com.smp.ravirathore.music W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
09-24 16:08:43.545    7216-7216/com.smp.ravirathore.music W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: add your logcat error

Comment: Your 'TextView' is in a different layout file than your `ListView` and your accessing that in `.FIleList` so it is force closing

Comment: So where should i place it?? i want the text typeface in the list view items

Comment: well i have uncommented THAT TEXTview inside but nothing happened ..it still getting force closed

Comment: Do you have journal.ttf in your assets folder?

Comment: where's your `imageView ` and also you will need to use an `Adapter` to display data in `ListView`

Comment: Well sorry , while adding to this website i have removed the imageview frim xml but forgot to remove from the java file. Well its not the cause actually ..previously also it was crashing before adding the image view

Comment: refer the  logcat error , that's the best practice of your Android Development carrier

Comment: i have updated the logcat ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity remove text View reference and everything related to textView and  update your text_list

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_list);
        backimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        listsongs = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_songs);
        ArrayList<File> songs = find(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
        genuinesongs = new String[songs.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i <= songs.size(); i++) {

            genuinesongs[i] = songs.get(i).getName().toString().replace("mp3","");
        }
      **UPDATED Adapter**
       ListAdapter  adp = new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), genuinesongs);
       listsongs.setAdapter(adp);
    }
```

**UPDATED**
**`textlistrow.xml`**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#bdbdbd"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:id="@+id/text_item"
            android:padding="10dp" />
```

**For Adding Custom Font**
if you need to add font to textview,you need create custom_item_layout and use it with Custom adapter and set font in `getView()` method.
Like

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
 String[] items;
    public ListAdapter(Context context,String[] items) {
        super(context,R.layout.itemlistrow,items);
        this.items=items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null); //inflate the list_row
         }


            TextView tv= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textitem);
             Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "journal.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(font);
             tv.setText(items[position]);

        }

        return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thnxx but So how can i add font ??

Comment: check that ive Updated the listitem name ,id of textview ,and Adpater in onCreate

Comment: its showing arrayadapter(Context, int)  cannot be applied to arrayadapter(Context, java.string[])

Comment: ive Updated `super(context,R.layout.itemlistrow,items);` in ListAdapter constructor

Comment: YOur solution was not upto the mark its getting force close.. i have updated the logcat please tell me what to do now?